# Paint store recommended satin finish paint to cover up very small spots on metal siding but same color is too shiny, how can I make it less shiny?

Tags: painting

Paint store recommended satin finish paint to cover up small down to the metal spots on metal siding, but using same color it looks lighter when in the shade, but almost a perfect match in sunlight.  Is it because it is a satin paint rather than a flat paint?  If so how can I make it look the same color regardless if its in shade or sunlight.  Paint store recommends not using a flat paint. I tried light sanding but it seems to have very little effect.

Comment: Almost impossible to hide a paint patch, you can get very close, but in the right light can usually see it.  The paint on the siding has had a chance to fade some, the new paint has not.

Comment: The _slightest_ mismatch in color or sheen will show up when the light changes. There's basically nothing you can do about that - it'll even happen on wood siding or painted drywall inside.

Comment: I've found that one of those Magic Erasers does a really good job of blending paint patches when the gloss levels don't match.  You'll never get it perfect, but the very light abrasive on those will help to buff out the stark differences.

Comment: I would try lightly sanding it with 400 grit (or higher) sandpaper. I would also sand the existing slightly if sanding the new is insufficient. Getting a perfect match is likely to prove impossible, but I think you can improve it significantly. Good luck!!